# Null array to empty list

Tags: java, arrays, collections

`Arrays.asList(E[] e)` returns a view of the array as a `List`, but when array is null it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
Arrays.asList(null); //NullPointerException.
```

Actually I'm doing

```
 List list = possibleNullArray != null ? Arrays.asList(possibleNullArray) : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

However, creating a Utility class in my project only for this purpose is a thing that I prefer not to do. Is there some utility Class, or library like Apache Commons or Guava to convert null arrays to empty `List`? (i.e. a null-safe converter between arrays and Collections).

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: ofcourse you will get NPE you set it as a null,  Arrays.asList(); converts your object as list of array / arraylist / array  if im not mistaken.

Comment: Is a good pratice to use empty collections o zero length array instead null, when you have readibility in mind. Im not discusing why Array.asList(null) throws a NullPointerException. This was a desing decision by its creator. Im asking about a utility class or library to convert null arras o collections to empty arrays or collections.

Comment: Please, if you downvote consider give a reason. Thanks.

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` and other similar methods e.g. `new ArrayList<>(...)` should not throw an NPE if the incoming collection is `null`, they should return an empty list. Throwing an NPE in this case is pretty ridiculous.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not aware of any util method in Apache Commons / Guava that would create an empty `List` instance out of null.

The best thing you can probably do is to initialize the possibly null array beforehand, e.g. with [`ArrayUtils.nullToEmpty()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#nullToEmpty(java.lang.Object[])). Get rid of the null as soon as you can.

```
SomeObject[] array = ArrayUtils.nullToEmpty(possiblyNullArray);
```

Comment: Also, you have raw `List` there. I hope your code is actually generified. There's no place for raw collections in new code.

Answer (score 45):

You can use Java 8 `Optional`:

```
String[] arr = null;
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(Optional.ofNullable(arr).orElse(new String[0]));
```

Comment: This. On Java 7, it's also possible to do with Guava's `Optional`. Or the same concept with a different code - Guava's `Objects.firstNonNull()`

Answer (score 21):

You can use Java 8 `Optional`and `Stream`

```
Optional.ofNullable(possibleNullArray)
        .map(Arrays::stream)
        .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```